# Succinct Event Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm interested in a succinct, preferably fluent way for testing events calls.  I've seen a couple examples that are close for related concepts (particularly with Moq), but haven't quite gotten there.

For example, I believe I should be able to achieve something like this, but with only a one or two liner for the test:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace EventTest
{
    public class TestClient
    {
        public event Action<string> Output;

        public bool Speak(string message)
        {
            if (Output != null)
            {
                Output(message);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class BasicActionTests
    {
        private TestClient Client;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            Client = new TestClient();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Speak()
        {
            const string message = "she sells sea shells by the sea shore - booyakasha!";

            System.Action<string> outDel = (output) =>
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(message, output);
            };

            Client.Output += outDel;

            try
            {
                bool success = Client.Speak(message);

                Assert.IsTrue(success, "Tongue Tied");
            }
            finally
            {
                Client.Output -= outDel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The key thing I want to retain here is that event is registered and unregistered within the test regardless of failure since the object is created in TestInitialize.  (I understand and agree that ideally we could test it without that as a clean unit test, but please let's just assume an integration test is necessary here.)

Ideally, I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
Assert.IsTrue(()=>Client.Speak(message)).VerifyEvent(obj => obj.Output, (msg) => Assert.AreEqual(message, msg));
```

where XXX could be a mock, or even just an Assert extension.

The closest example I've seen is [INCPTracer](https://gist.github.com/Seikilos/6224204), though it's not quite there (and to be honest I'd rather not include it for just this single use case, though I wouldn't mind including Moq since I use it heavily elsewhere, or another "widely used" framework/lib that provides other testing functionality).

Comment: Is it important that you aren't using the C# `event` keyword?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You're right John, just an omission on my part.  Updated and appreciated!